# NullPointerException caused by static field in Mapper class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a HBase MapReduce Bulkload application which include a customized `MyMapper` Class, and it has a static field `parser` which is used during the application running, When I config the job, I use `config` method to init the static field `parser`.

But when the job is running, the annotated line throws a null pointer exception, seems like after the job being submitted to Yarn, the static field `parser` becomes null.

This is the Mapper code, the version of hadoop is 2.7.7.

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> {

  private static StringParser parser;

  public static void config(StringParser parser) {
    MyMapper.parser = parser;
  }

  @Override
  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String lineValue = value.toString();
    String output;
    try {
      // null pointer exception this line.
      output = parser.parse(lineValue); 
      context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(..., ...);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code about the job submition:

```java
 
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Batch Import HBase Table：" + tableName);
    job.setJarByClass(TextBulkLoadDriver.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inPath);

    // Config Mapper related content, here I set the static field in MyMapper class.
    MyMapper.config(parser); 
    Class<MyMapper> cls = MyMapper.class;
    job.setMapperClass(cls);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job.setReducerClass(PutSortReducer.class);

    RegionLocator locator = instance.getConnection().getRegionLocator(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
    try (Admin admin = instance.getAdmin(); Table table = instance.getTable(tableName)) {
      HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table, locator);
      HFileOutputFormat2.setOutputPath(job, outPath);
      // run the job
      job.waitForCompletion(true);
      logger.info("HFileOutputFormat2 file ready on {}", outPath);
      LoadIncrementalHFiles loader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(conf);
      loader.doBulkLoad(outPath, admin, table, locator);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

TIA for all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are not sent to the distributed data processing in MapReduce. These variables are stored in memory only where the `jobTracker` is running and not in the executing nodes.

Yarn distributes the tasks to the nodes by serializing the task and sending that to the processing nodes. The static method `config` will not be going to get evaluated at every node, thus making the `parser` object null.

If you want to initialize the static variables, you might need to serialize the object and send it to each mapper.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still confused about how to "serialized and send" the object. because the `job` object use `class` object to set the `mapper`, and In my experience I used to `serialize` the objects within the class instances. Can you give me some additional advice?

Comment: You could use the https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/class-use/Configuration.html class to set the configuration for the parser and instantiate the parser inside the mapper code.


Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
parserConfig= config.getLong("parserConfig");
parser = ....